# If database is on another server in codeigniter application

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter application its work fine in local server. Now I want to upload it to on live server but in that my database is on another server, so I want to configure it.

I have changed the **application/config/database.php** file like this :

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xx.x.xxx.xx'; // ip address of that server
$db['default']['database'] = 'databasename';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['port'] = ':3306';
```

but its not working...

can any one give me answer please....

Thanks,
Upeksha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db['default']['port'] = ':3306';
```

To

```
$db['default']['port'] = '3306';
```